# returning inserted record using org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations

Tags: spring, spring-data

the insert method introduced by the MongoOperations in the spring data project does not return the inserted object, 
does anyone know a nice workaround for this issue?
thanks in advance :D

Comment: any particular reason for getting the document back that you have just written? you already have it...

Comment: to get the generated id :)

Answer (score -1):

I thought so, so the Id's are generated by the Java driver not mongodb. If spring mongo is not returning your the id back, you can generated ids yourself on the server and set it before you save it.